# Check if windows desktop app in running from react js

Tags: reactjs, windows

Is there any way I can detect from my ReactJs application whether a windows app is running or not?

Comment: If the React app is running inside a browser then you would need a custom browser plugin to provide this information to the JavaScript engine.  I don't know of any browser which provides this by default.

Comment: @David, you can also create a custom protocol (as it called on Windows) and bind it to a software that list the processes running in the client host and use it to send data back to the web application, using pooling from the React application to retrieve the information. An well-known example is `mailto`, that opens the email client installed on the system. This requires additional software to be installed and configured in the client PC. By the way I think this question can also refer to some malicious intention.

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli: True.  Either way, the OP is going to need something installed on the target machine.  Which then calls into question the use of a web application in the first place, since once one is in the space of an installed application then one may as well make use of that instead.

Comment: @David, yes, I agree on that. In this case it would be better to use a desktop application, even made with React and Electron, eventually, if this is the best option for this project.

Comment: Hmm, I see thank you for the information, so this is the way the games does to detect whether the anti-cheat app is running or not. It seems there is not an easy of handling this.

Comment: @AWIXOR, not an expert on that, maybe some detection-engine checks if there is any suspect behavior by analyzing the actions performed by an user, even with the help of an AI. If the mechanism is based on processes, there should be the need of some strategy to understand if a software is a cheat application. If an user changes the cheat application to appear as a different application, like notepad or similar, the anti-cheat mechanism may not be able to identify it correctly.